IHS server not starting.Getting error for Invalid VM
I have an IHS server where I have spcified multipl Virtual host. For each Virtual host I am getting this error
mod_ibm_ssl.c(2862): env_init entry
mod_ibm_ssl.c(2980): Processing SNI mappings in default vhost test-test.com
mod_ibm_ssl.c(295): SNI add k=invalid, v= , for vh=22575c0, parent_env=22f22b0
mod_ibm_ssl.c(305): Adding SNI mapping of 'invalid':' ' for VH
mod_ibm_ssl.c(2995): env_init exit

This error is there for all the virtual hosts. Entry in my httpd.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName test-test.com:443
</VirtualHost>

I have tried with and without :443 in the ServerName section but the result is same.

What does the global ErrorLog say?
